# Как разрешить доступ к команде только людям с определённым id?

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

Я пишу discord бота(discord.py) на python, и мне нужна функция, которая будет прибавляет к полю xp пользователя указанное число xp, если id того, кто её вызвал, находится в списке admins. Вот то что я сделал:

```
@bot.command()
async def add_xp(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, xp=None):
    """Функция add_xp прибавляет к полю xp пользователя указанное число xp.
    (только для админов).
    """
    if member is None:
        emb = discord.Embed(title="Укажите пользователя!", colour=discord.Colour.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    else:
        if xp is None:
            emb = discord.Embed(title="Укажите количество XP!", colour=discord.Colour.red())
            await ctx.send(embed=emb)
        else:
            emb = discord.Embed(title=f"Пользователю {member} добавлено {xp}XP", colour=discord.Colour.green())
            cursor.execute(f"UPDATE users SET xp = xp + {xp} WHERE id = {member.id}")
            await ctx.send(embed=emb)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Как реализовать проверку id пользователя? Желательно чтобы не внутри функции, а в декораторе каком-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать специальные декораторы:

- [`@commands.is_owner()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.is_owner)
- [`@commands.has_role('Admin')`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_role)
- [`@commands.has_any_role('Admin', 'Administrator')`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role)
- [`@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True, ban_members=True)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions)

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord as ds
import config

bot = commands.Bot(commands.when_mentioned_or(config.bot_prefix), owner_ids=config.owner_ids)

@commands.is_owner()
async def test1(ctx):
    await ctx.reply('You\'re owner! In owner_ids!')

@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def test2(ctx):
    await ctx.reply('You have role "Admin"!')

@commands.has_role(11432413241)
async def test3(ctx):
    await ctx.reply('You have role by id 11432413241!')

@commands.has_any_role('Admin', 'Administrator')
async def test4(ctx):
    await ctx.reply('You have role "Admin" or "Administrator"!')

@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True, ban_members=True)
async def test5(ctx):
    await ctx.reply('You can administer the server and ban members!')

bot.run(config.ds_token, reconnect=True)
```

config.py

```py
ds_token = '<token>'
guild_ids = {<guild_id>}
owner_ids = {<your_id>}
bot_prefix = '<command_prefix>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Получить имя автора вызванной команды:

```
username = ctx.message.author.name
```

Если хотите посмотреть в сторону декораторов, то могу предложить такой вектор решения:

```
admins = ['admin'] # список администраторов

def admin_access(username):
def wrapper(func):
    if username in admins: # проверяем находится ли пользователь в списке администраторов
        func() # вызываем функцию прибавления XP
    else:
        ... # выводим уведомление при необходимости
        print('Пользователь не администратор') 
return wrapper

@admin_access(username='admin')
@bot.command()
async def add_xp(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, xp=None):
...
```